# Writing $\vec{j}(\vec{x}')$ given the current $I$, using the $\delta$ function

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a thin ring of radius $R$ with a current $I$ in the $X-Y$ plane.

In order to find $\vec{A}$ via $\vec{A}(\vec{x})=\frac 1 c \iiint\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{x}')d^3 x'}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}$ I needed to figure out what $\vec{j}(\vec{x}')$ is.

I decided to use the $\delta$ function and wrote $\vec{j}(\vec{x}')=\frac{I}{2\pi R}\delta(r'-R)\frac{\delta(\theta '-\frac \pi 2)}{r'}\hat{\phi '}=\frac{I}{2\pi R^2}\delta(r'-R)\delta(\theta '-\frac \pi 2)\hat{\phi '}$.

I also checked $I=\iiint{j(\vec{x}') d^3 x'}$, which is indeed the case.

However, in my study material, they say $\vec{j}(\vec{x}')=\frac I {R\sin{\theta}}\delta(r'-R)\delta(\theta '-\frac \pi 2)\hat{\phi '}$.

I don't see how they got this, and why my $\vec{j}(\vec{x}')$ is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the current should satisfy

\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \int{\rm d}^3{\bf r}~{\bf j}({\bf r}) = \int{\rm d}\phi{\rm d\cos\theta}{\rm d}\frac{r^3}{3}~{\bf j}(\phi,\cos\theta,r^3/3)
\end{eqnarray}

In your case

\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf j}(\phi,\cos\theta,r^3/3) &=& I
\color{red}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}}_{\rm c.f.~d\phi}}
\color{blue}{\underbrace{\delta(\cos\theta - \cos\pi/2)}_{\rm c.f.~d\cos\theta}}
\color{orange}{\underbrace{\delta(r^3/3 - R^3/3)}_{\rm c.f.~dr^3/3}}
\hat{\phi} \\
&=& \frac{I}{2\pi R^2} \delta(\theta - \pi/2)\delta(r - R) \hat{\phi} 
\end{eqnarray}

where I have used the property

$$
\delta(f(x)) = \frac{1}{|f'(x_0)|}\delta(x-x_0)
$$

for a simple pole $x_0$ and a similar expression for higher order poles.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems like, by using the property you mentioned, you should have $R^2=|(\frac{r^3}3)'(R)|$ in the denominator instead of  $R$, and $1=|(\cos\theta)'(\pi/2)|$ instead of $\sin\theta$. And then you get my answer. Am I correct?

Comment: @Whyka You're right